# Can I configure the Radiator View in Hudson/Jenkins?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

My team uses the [Radiator View](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Radiator+View+Plugin) plugin for [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) for fast feedback on the build status of a few different projects. One thing we discussed that would be helpful is if the SVN revision number were included in this view. After only a quick Google search, I haven't found a clear answer on whether this plugin is configurable or not; does anyone know if there's a straightforward way to add this information?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there are customizable figures there but what you can do is, pull down the source and get the revsion numbers for all the failing builds, you will have to write the code yourself, but from what I can see there is no way of doing this with the configuration options.

What you might want to try if you just need to get that information is the recent changes on the build page of the recently broken build.

Goodluck.

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask why it would be helpful to have the svn revision number on display? As far as I understand it, a build radiator is supposed to 'radiate' meaningful information into the room. The svn number is fairly meaningless unless you can look up the number in the repository, in which case you could have just looked up the revision number on Jenkins anyway.

I'm just guessing, and do correct me if I'm wrong, but I suspect that your real desire is to have some way of quickly working out who might be responsible for a failing build. If this is the case, then processing check-in comments and displaying pictures of the users involved is a far more effective way of getting developers to react to failing builds. I've experienced this first hand at my company.

With this in mind, I have developed a standalone build radiator webapp that talks to Jenkins over its REST API. CI-Eye is trivial to set up, and will probably give you better results in the workplace than the *Radiator View* plug-in. Give it a try, and let me know what you think -- I'm quite actively improving it, and welcome any feedback.

**CI-Eye is free and open source** -- see the [CI-Eye wiki](https://github.com/netmelody/ci-eye/wiki) for more details.